# Can't assign struct field in an if branch where the borrow won't happen

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to achieve the following general logic:

1. When the `token` is valid, return it.
2. Otherwise, do something to get a valid one, assign it to the `token`, then return it too.

What I've done for now is:

```
pub struct SomeStruct {
    ...
    token: Option<String>,
}

impl SomeStruct {
    fn token(&mut self) -> Option<&str> {
        // if token is valid
        if let Some(t) = self.token.as_deref() {
            // ... some other checks
            return Some(&t);
        }

        if let Ok(t) = fs::read_to_string("Somewhere...") {
            self.token = Some(t); // here the compiler complains.
            return self.token.as_deref();
        }

        return None;
    }
}
```

But the compiler won't let me do it this way, it says:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `self.token` because it is borrowed
  --> src\blabla\blablabla.rs:46:13
   |
31 |     fn token(&mut self) -> Option<&str> {
   |              - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
32 |         // if token and token_mtime are valid
33 |         if let Some(t) = self.token.as_deref() {
   |                          --------------------- `self.token` is borrowed here
...
39 |                 return Some(&t);
|                        -------- returning this value requires that `self.token` is borrowed for `'1`
...
46 |             self.token = Some(t);
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^ `self.token` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
```

I tried to change the return type to `Option<String>` and remove the `.as_deref()` but then **move** happens...

For me, the **assign** appears in an if branch that the **borrow** won't even happen, as the `return Some(&t)` is skipped. So why does the compiler still complain?

I'm so confused why this happens, and wondering how may I achieve this simple goal. I googled a lot, but not lucky enough to find an answer...

Could someone please help me out, at least explain to me why, so I can figure out a way out myself.

Comment: In short: this is a known limitation of the current borrow checker. The workaround is instead of `if let Some() = x` to have `if x.is_some() { return x.unwrap() }`.